# Laravel 5.3: How do I map all urls under a prefix to one controller method?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, url-pattern

I have a route group under a prefix `admin`:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@method');
});
```

I would like a url such as `/admin/dashboard/` and `/admin/blogmanager/`, basically, **any arbitrary url** under the `admin` prefix to be mapped to the *same controller `method`* without listing each url one by one. I would like a url pattern to accept all urls as long as it is prefixed by `admin`

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with `Route::controller()` method but it was removed from Laravel and I think it's for good, because all routes should be explicit.

You can use [`Route::resource()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers) fro CRUD controllers.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Your response has made me realize that this may be a design issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use {any} syntax:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function(){
    Route::get('{any}', 'AdminController@handle');
});
```

Every route with prefix admin will be handled by AdminController.

If you want urls like: /admin/profile/post,... use:

```
Route::get('{any}', 'AdminController@handle')->where('any', '.*');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function(){
     Route::get('{any_url?}', 'AdminController@method');
});
```

With this all route with prefix admin will be handled by AdminController.
And your AdminController should look like this.

```
Class AdminController extends Controller{

      public function method($any_url = NULL){
         //Put some conditions here
      }
}
```